# How to know if a non-blocking socket is closed?

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

I'm trying to write **my own** TCP Non-Blocking Server to handle multiple long lasting socket connections rather than opening many threads to handle them.

I've written my over-complicated, hard to use syntax but have the issue forms when I'm trying to detect a closed socket.

In a normal threaded TCP Socket Server I would use detected a `b''` from the `socket.read(size)` function, However this is not possible with a nonblocking socket as it will always return a `BlockingIOError`

I have also tried catching theese following events

```py
except BrokenPipeError:
    conn.abort()
except ConnectionResetError:
    conn.abort()
except ConnectionAbortedError:
    conn.abort()
except socket.error:
    conn.abort()
```

*(`conn` is a class that houses the client socket and address from `socket.accept()`)*

I'm unsure what to do, but here is a deeply simplified extract from my code:

```py
def loop_listen(self):
    while self.running == True:
    cr, addr = self.server.accept()
    crs = SocketHandler(self, cr, addr)
    self.client_handler(crs)
    self.connections.append(crs)
    crs.events["open"]()
    crs.cr.setblocking(0)

def loop_recv(self):
    while self.running == True:
        time.sleep(self.poll_time)

        for conn in self.connections:
        try:
            data = conn.cr.recv(self.poll_size)
            print(data)
            if (data == b''):
                conn.abort()
        except BlockingIOError:
            data = None
        except BrokenPipeError:
            conn.abort()
        except ConnectionResetError:
            conn.abort()
        except ConnectionAbortedError:
            conn.abort()
        except socket.error:
            conn.abort()
        if (data != None):
            conn.events["msg"](data)
```

*(Both loops are separate threads)*

And incase you wanted it, here is the `conn` class

```py
class SocketHandler:
    def __init__(self, server, cr, addr):
        self.server = server
        self.cr = cr
        self.addr = addr
        self.events = {"msg": emptyCallback, "close": "emptyCallback","open":emptyCallback}
        self.cache = b""

    def message(self, func):
        self.events["msg"] = func

    def close(self, func):
        self.events["close"] = func

    def open(self, func):
        self.events["open"] = func

    def send(self, data):
        self.cr.send(data)
    def abort(self):
        self.cr.close()
        self.events["close"]()
        self.server.connections.remove(conn)
```

This works fine on Windows but on Ubuntu it does not call the `conn.abort()`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Sam.

Comment: If the connection is closed, the recv should return immediately with a zero-length bytes object. What does the `print(data)` statement give you after the other side closed the connection? Also, consider using `select` to wait for events on the socket instead of sleeping between polls.

Comment: The recv does not give me back an empty bytes object after disconnect as mentioned above, the `print(data)` outputs `b'Hello World'` (the message it should receive)

Comment: You call `abort` on your socket class. But do you actually remove it from `self.connections`?

Comment: Yes `self.server.connections.remove(conn)`

Comment: This question is not about the socket being closed. It is about the *connection* being closed by the peer. The socket is not closed. Otherwise you couldn't read from it at all.

Answer (score 2):

The official way to detect a closed connection on a non-blocking socket is exactly the same as blocking sockets. They return empty data from `recv()`.

Example:

```
# Server
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('localhost', 12345))
s.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    conn.setblocking(0)
    print("New connection from " + str(addr) + ".")
    while True:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            print("Received:", data)
        except BlockingIOError:
            time.sleep(0.001) 

    print("Closed.")
```

```
# Client
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 12345))

for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(0.3)
    s.send(str(i).encode('utf-8'))
s.close()
```

There is one special case where this won't work, as described in the official docs, section [When Sockets Die](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#when-sockets-die). It happens, when sockets don't shut down gracefully. There basically is no way for `recv()` to detect when a socket is dead without a graceful shutdown. It might be that this is what you are seeing.

There are multiple ways to resolve that. For one, create some kind of timeout that closes and discards a socket if it didn't receive a message for a sensible amount of time. Secondly, you could actively send messages. Detecting a dead socket is much easier for `send()` than for `recv()`.

Further, this works on Linux. I didn't test it on Windows. The internal implementation of the sockets class is very platform dependent, so it might be a Windows bug.

Comment: Hello, The only output I get from is the message from the client. The code should handle a empty bytes to detect a close yet it does not work. This is because the `.recv()` function raises a `BlockingIOError` error. This fit in with what you mention

Comment: It works for me, definitely. Which operating system are you on?

Comment: Is there anyway to send that wont harm the trafic? I'm dealing with HTTP Traffic and WS traffic, and from past experience it can be temperamental

Comment: Which python version? I run Linux Mint 19.1 (=Ubuntu 18.04) with Python 3.6.7, and it definitely works. But I remember having problems in the past. Might have been a bug, and got patched in newer versions. Anyway, not sure what else to say ... I don't think another way exists, if this one doesn't work, I'm afraid you either have to do blocking sockets or a different language ...
I'm not sure if there are any ways to ping HTTP/WS connections, sorry :/

Comment: I was running 3.5.2 but installed 3.7 with still no luck. Gonna Explore TCP_INFO to try poll the socket state. Thanks for your help! -Sam

Comment: Good luck ... sounds like a dumb workaround for something that python *should* have implemented correctly. Yay. To make sure it is not an operating system problem, I would write a short test in C, directly utilizing the socket api. It would be interesting if it behaves the same.

Comment: It isn't OS-dependent. The Python guys have screwed up somehow. The behaviour is specified in the Sockets API.

Comment: Yah, I know, but I mean the implementation is heavily os-dependent. Inside the library. Therefore it isn't surprising a bug like this only exists on one version of one OS.

Comment: So you should say 'the implementation of sockets *in Python*'.

Comment: I disagree, I think it is quite clear how to understand it. Nonetheless I changed it to stop further discussion.